# "invalid column index" error while inserting data to DB using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I am new to hibernate. I am using hibernate to insert the data to the DB. While inserting the data to the DB getting **"invalid column index"** error. I am using OnetoMany mapping in hibernate. Please let me know if I have implemented something wrong doing the onetomany mapping in the hibernate. Please help me in this. Any help is really appretiated. Please refer my code entity classes below -

**Parent Class -->**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent_Table")

public class ParentEntity implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4805702152070138493L;
private long my_Id;
private String my_Name;
private long locNbr;
private Timestamp createTs;
private String createUsrId;
private Timestamp lstUpdTs;
private String lstUpdUsrId;
private Integer version;
private List<ChildEntity> childInfo = new ArrayList<ChildEntity>(0);

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "MY_ID_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "MY_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "MY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public long getMyId() {
    return my_Id;
}

public void setMyId(long my_Id) {
    this.my_Id = my_Id;
}

@Column(name = "MY_NAME", nullable = false)
public String getMy_Name() {
    return my_Name;
}

public void setMy_Name(String my_Name) {
    this.my_Name = my_Name;
}

@Column(name = "LOC_NBR", nullable = false)
public long getLocNbr() {
    return locNbr;
}

public void setLocNbr(long locNbr) {
    this.locNbr = locNbr;
}

@Column(name = "CREATE_TS", nullable = false)
public Timestamp getCreateTs() {
    return createTs;
}

public void setCreateTs(Timestamp createTs) {
    this.createTs = createTs;
}

@Column(name = "CREATE_USR_ID", nullable = false)
public String getCreateUsrId() {
    return createUsrId;
}

public void setCreateUsrId(String createUsrId) {
    this.createUsrId = createUsrId;
}

@Column(name = "LST_UPD_TS", nullable = false)
public Timestamp getLstUpdTs() {
    return lstUpdTs;
}

public void setLstUpdTs(Timestamp lstUpdTs) {
    this.lstUpdTs = lstUpdTs;
}

@Column(name = "LST_UPD_USR_ID", nullable = false)
public String getLstUpdUsrId() {
    return lstUpdUsrId;
}

public void setLstUpdUsrId(String lstUpdUsrId) {
    this.lstUpdUsrId = lstUpdUsrId;
}

@Column(name = "VERSION")
@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MY_ID", nullable = false)
public List<ChildEntity> getchildInfo() {
    return childInfo;
}

public void setchildInfo(List<ChildEntity> childInfo) {
    this.childInfo = childInfo;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ParentEntity other = (ParentEntity) obj;
    if (my_Id != other.my_Id)
        return false;
    if (my_Name == null) {
        if (other.my_Name != null)
            return false;
    }else if (!my_Name.equals(other.my_Name))
        return false;
    if(childInfo == null){
        if(other.childInfo != null)
            return false;
    }else if (!childInfo.equals(other.childInfo))
        return false;
    if (locNbr != other.locNbr)
        return false;
    return true;
}

  @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (my_Id ^ (my_Id >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + (int) (locNbr ^ (locNbr >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((my_Name == null) ? 0 : my_Name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((childInfo == null) ? 0 : childInfo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

}
```

**Child Class -->**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child_Table")
@IdClass(ChildEntityPK.class)

public class ChildEntity implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4195294854422389625L;
private long my_Id;
private long deptNbr;
private long locNbr;
private Timestamp createTs;
private String createUsrId;
private Integer version;
private ParentEntity parent;

@Id
@Column(name = "MY_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public long getMyId() {
    return my_Id;
}
public void setMyId(long my_Id) {
    this.my_Id = my_Id;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "DEPT_NBR", nullable = false)
public long getDeptNbr() {
    return deptNbr;
}
public void setDeptNbr(long deptNbr) {
    this.deptNbr = deptNbr;
}

@Column(name = "LOC_NBR", nullable = false)
public long getLocNbr() {
    return locNbr;
}
public void setLocNbr(long locNbr) {
    this.locNbr = locNbr;
}

@Column(name = "CREATE_TS", nullable = false)
public Timestamp getCreateTs() {
    return createTs;
}
public void setCreateTs(Timestamp createTs) {
    this.createTs = createTs;
}

@Column(name = "CREATE_USR_ID", nullable = false)
public String getCreateUsrId() {
    return createUsrId;
}
public void setCreateUsrId(String createUsrId) {
    this.createUsrId = createUsrId;
}

@Column(name = "VERSION")
@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "MY_ID", referencedColumnName = "MY_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public ParentEntity getParent() {
    return parent;
}
public void setParent(ParentEntity parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ChildEntity other = (ChildEntity) obj;
    if (my_Id != other.my_Id)
        return false;
    if (deptNbr != other.deptNbr)
        return false;
    if (locNbr != other.locNbr)
        return false;
    if (parent == null) {
        if (other.parent != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!parent.equals(other.parent))
        return false;
    return true;
}

  @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (my_Id ^ (my_Id >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + (int) (deptNbr ^ (deptNbr >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + (int) (locNbr ^ (locNbr >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((parent == null) ? 0 : parent.hashCode());
        return result;
    }



}
```

**ChildPk Class --**

```
public class ChildEntityPK implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5118485760469581332L;
private long my_Id;
private long deptNbr;

@Id
@Column(name = "MY_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public long getMy_Id) {
    return my_Id;
}
public void setMy_Id(long my_Id) {
    this.my_Id = my_Id;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "DEPT_NBR", nullable = false)
public long getDeptNbr() {
    return deptNbr;
}
public void setDeptNbr(long deptNbr) {
    this.deptNbr = deptNbr;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ChildEntityPK other = (ChildEntityPK) obj;
    if (my_Id != other.my_Id)
        return false;
    if (deptNbr != other.deptNbr)
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + (int) (my_Id ^ (my_Id >>> 32));
    result = prime * result + (int) (deptNbr ^ (deptNbr >>> 32));
    return result;
}


}
```

**ERROR --**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setLongInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4936) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setLong(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4923) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setLong(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:210) [ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.setLong(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:229)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:57) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:284) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:279) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:343) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2835) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2804) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3076) [hibernate-core-4.2.18.Final-redhat-2.jar:4.2.18.Final-redhat-2]
... 91 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788243/hibernate-collection-invalid-column-index

Comment: add the method that makes the actual save

Comment: Can find the solution in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717965/jpa-annotation-for-parent-composite-key-to-be-part-of-child-composite-primary-ke/59118299#59118299